# Type Erasure with void pointer stored in vector of unique_ptr issues when copying

Tags: c++, memory, unique-ptr, void-pointers, type-erasure

I've been banging my head on a crash that has to do with copy assignment of an object that holds a vector of unique_ptr that point to a class that hides std::vector data behind a void *. I have taken care of writing copy operator overloads so that the unique_ptr objects are copied correctly along their owning object.

Below is a minimal example of the issue. When executing the code, a crash relating to undefined memory happens when A is copied into B, the DataHolderImpl class is fed corrupted memory in it's set() method during the cloning of the object.

Any help would be really appreciated, this seems out of my depth and I'm not sure what to look for at this stage. Thanks !

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

class DataHolderBase {
    public:
        DataHolderBase() {};
        virtual ~DataHolderBase() {};
        virtual std::unique_ptr<DataHolderBase> clone() const = 0;
};

class DataHolderImpl : public DataHolderBase {
    public:
        DataHolderImpl() : DataHolderBase() {
            m_data = new std::vector<float>;
        }

        ~DataHolderImpl() {
            delete reinterpret_cast<std::vector<float> *>(m_data);
        }

        std::unique_ptr<DataHolderBase> clone() const override {
            DataHolderBase * copy = new DataHolderImpl(*this);
            return std::unique_ptr<DataHolderBase>(copy);
        }

        void setVector(std::vector<float> const & data) {
            if(m_data) {
                delete reinterpret_cast<std::vector<float> *>(m_data);
            }
            m_data = (void *)malloc(sizeof(float) * data.size());
            memcpy(m_data, data.data(), sizeof(float) * data.size());
        }

        void set(void * data) {
            std::vector<float> * vec = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<float> *>(data);
            setVector(*vec);
        }

        void* get() const {
            return m_data;
        }

        DataHolderImpl(DataHolderImpl const & other) : 
                DataHolderBase(other),
                m_data(nullptr)
            {
                set(other.get());
            }

            DataHolderImpl(DataHolderImpl && other) = default;

            DataHolderImpl& operator=( DataHolderImpl const & other )
            {
                if(this != &other) {
                    set(other.get());
                }
                return *this;
            };

            DataHolderImpl& operator=( DataHolderImpl&& other ) = default;

    private:
        void * m_data;
};

class MyObject {
    public:
        MyObject() {
            m_dataHolders.push_back(std::make_unique<DataHolderImpl>());
        };
        ~MyObject() {};

        MyObject(MyObject const & other)
        {
            m_dataHolders = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataHolderBase>>();
            m_dataHolders.reserve(other.m_dataHolders.size());
            for(auto const & dataHolder : other.m_dataHolders) {
                m_dataHolders.push_back(dataHolder->clone());
            }
        }

        MyObject(MyObject && other) = default;
        
        MyObject& operator=( MyObject const & other )
        {
            if (this != &other)
            {
                m_dataHolders = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataHolderBase>>();
                m_dataHolders.reserve(other.m_dataHolders.size());
                for(auto const & dataHolder : other.m_dataHolders) {
                    m_dataHolders.push_back(dataHolder->clone());
                }
            }
            return *this;
        };

        MyObject& operator=( MyObject&& other ) = default;

    private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataHolderBase>> m_dataHolders;
};

class Test {
    public:
        Test() : m_A(), m_B()
        {
            m_B = m_A;
        }
    private:
        MyObject m_A;
        MyObject m_B;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto A = Test();
    auto B = A; // <- Crashes here.
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do [these warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/E9d7ed73b) help? It's probably not a good idea to even try to run a program that produces those warnings when compiling it.
It's not only that you try to `delete` a `void*`, you allocate _one_ element in _`void*`_ `m_data = new std::vector<float>;` but try to `delete` an array in `delete [] m_data;`

Comment: You can't `memcpy` a `std::vector`'s value.

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem.

Comment: Using a raw pointer allocated with new, is an assurance for nightmares. The rule of 3/5 says that you will need a custom dtor, and custom copy and move ctors and assignment operators... Do you really need that design?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have updated the code in the original post so it builds on compiler explorer. It throws a heap-buffer-overflow now, which makes some sense but I'm pretty newbie when it comes to this.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm well aware this is nightmare land but I would like to figure out this implementation, even if it stays as minimal as this, to do some comparisons with other approaches. I would also like to understand what's happening so I can deal with it better if it happens again.

Comment: @aschepler The actual problem is type erasure of a set of std::vector types that needs to be very very efficient for read/writes. I would like to avoid templates and was wondering how an old school implementation of this would look like.

Comment: @Tuft Your `DataHolderImpl` copy constructor and copy assignment are just copying the pointer. Then you have two instances both trying to delete the pointer. You also cannot copy non-trivial types by `memcpy`. All of this causes undefined behavior.

Comment: I am not sure how you want to use this (maybe provide a usage example in the question), but it seems to me that `DataHolderImpl` should just hold a `std::unique_ptr` to the vector or the vector itself and be templated on the specific vector type.

Comment: Ask yourself what m_data points to (if not null). Is it std::vector<float> (as in the constructor) or is it a sequence of floats (as in setVector)?

Comment: Why do you need to erase the type of the vector when it's already hidden in the *private* section of the class?